# How to install C compilator on OpenWrt?

Tags: c, gcc, openwrt

I'm using OpenWrt and I would need to compile a .c file on OpenWrt. So, I think I need to install gcc. Anyway:

```
root@OpenWrt:/mnt# opkg install gcc
Unknown package 'gcc'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package gcc.
root@OpenWrt:/mnt#
```

Why is this happening? I'm connected to internet.

Comment: Home routers tend to not be very strong or capable when it comes to raw processing power. Which means you really shouldn't try to build applications *on* them. See if you can find a *cross-compiler* for your own computer, to build applications that can be installed on the router.

Comment: Try to update your packages DB first with `opkg update` then install GCC with `opkg install gcc`. It's not a good solution to install compiler/toolchain on your router. It's better to cross-compile your code on a workstation then upload binary on the router.